# ajax передача файла в php функцию

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма

```
    <form class="row" action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="col-md-9">                                                                                  
         <input class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="userfile" type="file" size="50">
      </div>                                
     <div class="col-md-3">                                                                                 
        <input class="btn btn-default user_up btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" style="    height: 36px;">
     </div>
  </form>
```

Есть Ajax запрос

```
$(".face").on('mouseup','li',function(e){
               if($(this).hasClass('nm')){
                    var person_id=$(this).find('.user-info b').attr('my');
                        $(".user_up").on('click',function(e){
                            $.ajax({
                                     type: 'GET',
                                     url: "index.php?route=proc_in_develop_video&metod=face_ftp",
                                     data: "person_id="+person_id+"",
                                     success: function (data) {
                                     alert(data);
                                      }
                                  });
                            });
                    }
            });
```

Как с помощью ajax передать файл?

Comment: `type: 'GET',` => `type: 'POST',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опуская логику вашего скрипта:

```
    // <form id="some-form" ...


    var formData = new FormData($("form#some-form")); // собирает данные, кодирует в multipart/form-data

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=proc_in_develop_video&metod=face_ftp',
        type: 'post', // для форм с типом содержимого multipart/form-data используйте post
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, // важно! что бы границы аргументов запроса сохранились
        processData: false // важно! что бы данные с файлом при передаче не преобразовывались в строку
        success: function (data) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
           // если что-то не так с запросом, объект xhr вернёт подробный отчёт
        }
    });
...
return false; // если форма сабмитится стандартно, кнопкой type="submit", это событие надо приглушить.
```

Там, куда отправили, смотрите массивы `$_POST` и `$_FILES`

[Про ajax тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

[Про FormData тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: а как в запросе еще person_id передать?

Comment: Объект FormData собирёт все интуты формы, которую вы уму передадите. Там по ссылке про FormData всё это есть.