# Кодировка при отладке отправки формы через ajax + FormData

Tags: php, ajax

При отладке отправки формы через ajax, я обычно открываю URL отправки через браузер.
При отправке формы через serialize() - кодировка русских символов в отладочном окне - нормальная. А при отправке через FormData весь русский текст - коверкается и при открытии окна браузера, в базу пишутся кривые значения.
Если не открывать окно, то обработка в части кодировки проходит нормально.

Вопрос, как при открытии окна для отладки сделать, что бы кодировка была нормальная.

Comment: Параметры аякс запроса при отправке сериализованных значений и объекта FormData отличаются. Добавьте к вопросу листинг вашего запроса. И на всяк посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965982/ajax-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-php-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E/966031#966031

Comment: Как получить листинг запроса?
Пробовал объект FormData преобразовать в json и вывести в console.log.
 так там все нормально.
Те нужно или сделать, что бы при отладке отображались правильно русские символы или ипользовать какой то другой метод отладки, не через окно браузера.